# Visual Studio 2017 not refreshing dependency correctly (but 2015 does)

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution in which **Project A** (a web application) is dependent on **Project B** (a class library). In Visual Studio 2015, if I built **Project B** its DLL would automatically refresh within **Project A**'s bin folder so that the new code was used in my web application. However, in Visual Studio 2017 the DLL for **Project B** in the web application's folder is not refreshed, requiring that I do a full solution rebuild anytime a change is made in **Project B**. This is time consuming.

With both VS 2015 and VS 2017 open side by side I can re-create this behavior reliably. I'm thinking there's some subtle change in the project/solution file structure that's changed in VS2017 that's not being recognized perhaps?

Any thoughts on what I'm not accounting for?